# American football delay of game

Tags: rules, american-football

Scenario:

- Your team is up by 5.
- There are 5 minutes remaining in the game.
- It is 4th down and goal-to-go from the opponent’s 40 yard line (you’ve
  had a lot of penalties).
- Your punter can guarantee hang-time of 10 seconds, but his minimum distance is 41 yards beyond the line of scrimmage.
- Your placekicker has been in the league for 20 years and
  has never successfully kicked a field goal longer than 50 yards,
  after having tried 100 times.

In order to provide room for your punter, you take a delay-of-game penalty in order to push the line of scrimmage back to the opponent’s 45.

Question:  can the defense decline the penalty?
If yes, can you take another delay-of-game penalty?  What would cause you to ever snap the ball on time?

Comment: If your punter is incapable of punting less than 40 yards, he's getting you enough field position normally that you probably should just take the touchback here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rule 14 Section 6 Article 4

> "When a 40/25-second penalty occurs prior to the snap, the defensive
>   team  may decline a distance penalty, in which case the down is
>   replayed from the previous spot."

Rule 4  Section 7 Note 1:

> "Two successive delay penalties during the same down, is
>   unsportsmanlike conduct [...]"

Rule 12 Section 3 Article 1

> "There shall be no unsportsmanlike conduct. This applies to any act
>   which is contrary to the generally understood principles of
>   sportsmanship. Such acts specifically include, among others: [...]  o.
>   Two successive delay-of-game penalties during the same down. [...]
>
> Penalty: For unsportsmanlike conduct (for (j) through (v)): Loss of 15
>   yards from: a)the succeeding spot if the ball is dead [...]"

Source: http://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/2015-nfl-rulebook

Comment: Ah but the defense could still decline the unsportsmanlike conduct penalty.

Comment: I think the additional penalty wouldn't really help there: 55 yards back now, you're probably ending up with them at the 20 anyway.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, too, the defense would willingly accept that 15-yard penalty.